# How to remove double quotes in value reading from csv file

Tags: python, string, csv

My csv file:

```
Mp4,Mp3,"1234554"
```

My code:

```
csv=csv=b''.join(csv).split(b'\n')
for index,row in enumerate(csv):
  row=re.split(b''',(?=(?:[^'"]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*$)''',row)
  for records in row:
      print(records)
```

when it printing the records ,for the 3rd element it prints with ""i need to ignore this doubles quotes.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `pandas`?

Comment: Use the `csv` built-in module or `pandas.read_csv` 3rd party module function to read the file

Comment: Yes due to third party previlages

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
records = records.replace("\"","")
```

### Edit

---

Using `pandas.read_csv` is better for working with csv files

```
import pandas as pd
csv = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=',', names=['x', 'y', 'z'])

# iterate over the dataframe
for index, row in csv.iterrows():
    print(row['x'], row['y'], row['z'])
```

Assuming content of `data.csv` looks like

```
Mp4,Mp3,"1234554"
```

The Output would look like this:

```
Mp4 Mp3 1234554
```

If your csv file includes column names e.g.

```
file_type1,file_type2,size
mp4,mp3,"1234554"
```

Just remove the `names` parameter if you read in the csv file:

```
csv = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=',')
print(csv)
```

Then the Output would look like this:

```
  file_type1 file_type2     size
0        mp4        mp3  1234554
```

Read more about [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) or [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: As per organisational policy,am not allowed to install pandas ,opnepyxl,xlrd and other packages

Answer (score 0):

You could easlily replace it with

```
print(records.replace('"',''))
```